# How to fix this regular expression error?

Tags: php, regex

This regular expression variable not working with my `preg_match` function:

Form

```
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
         <label for="f_name">First Name</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="f_name" name="f_name" >
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
         <label for="l_name">Last Name</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="l_name" name="l_name" >
       </div>
    </div><br>

    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
          <button id="signup_button" name="signup_button" class="btn btn-success" style="font-family: Roboto;font-size: 15px;">
             Create Account
          </button>
       </div>
   </div>
```

This is javascript

```
    $("#signup_button").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url     : "register.php",
        method  : "POST",
        data    : $("form").serialize(),
        success : function(data){
            $("#signup_msg").html(data);
        }
    })

})
```

This is php file..

```
$f_name = $_POST['f_name'];
$name = "/^ [A-Z] [a-zA-Z ]+$/";

if (!preg_match($name,$f_name))
{
 echo "$f_name is not valid";
 exit();
}
```

When I type correct name it says invalid Screen shot attached below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdYJj.png)

What ever text I enter it says `$f_name` is not Valid. I guess the Regular expression is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind, a space is a valid part of an regular expression - you cant use spaces, to seperate parts of your regular expression (except, you use some regex modifiers..).

In your case, `A a` would be an valid input. To change this behavior, your remove the spaces from your regex.

```
$name = "/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+$/";
```

Comment: @ThomasRollet how should I know his requirements - he just wrote the regex isn't working, and my guess is, that's not working because of  the spaces. If he want `NAME Firstname`, he might better use something like `/^[A-Z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+$/`

Comment: @ThomasRollet Its not working even after removing space, it says not valid whatever I type

Comment: @ARMkhan Edit your post and show us the form code please. And what you tried to type ?

Comment: @ARMkhan Do you want to check the `Name` AND `Firstname` with your regex or just your `Firstname` ?

Comment: @ThomasRollet yes both

Comment: @ThomasRollet this is the tutorial I was following and its working in it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6DtGerpUAM&list=PLB_Wd4-5SGAbYqmJ4OVF24g0lNFnUap-W&index=13

Comment: @ThomasRollet Thanks for the help bro i found the issue it was a cache problem when I clear it it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex :

```
/^[A-Z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+$/
```

In future, you can use this type of site to test your regex : https://regex101.com/

Hope it helps you

Comment: Why should the OP "try this regex"?  A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: What have you type to do it ?